# java.io.FileNotFoundException in URL

Tags: java, android

I am making an app to send notification when it release news on a site (https://www.noticiasaominuto.com/tech), but when I go to run the following error occurs:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.noticiasaominuto.com/tech

Full Stack trace:

> 12-20 16:36:41.135 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.noticiasaominuto.com/tech
>   12-20 16:36:41.135 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
>   12-20 16:36:41.135 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>   12-20 16:36:41.135 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>   12-20 16:36:41.135 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at test.m4ur0.inovar.GetNota.doInBackground(GetNota.java:41)
>   12-20 16:36:41.135 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at test.m4ur0.inovar.GetNota.doInBackground(GetNota.java:13)
>   12-20 16:36:41.136 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>   12-20 16:36:41.136 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   12-20 16:36:41.136 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>   12-20 16:36:41.136 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   12-20 16:36:41.136 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   12-20 16:36:41.136 6835-7089/test.m4ur0.inovar W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

If someone can help-me, this is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String nota = "";

    String sURL = "https://www.noticiasaominuto.com/tech";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Host", "https://www.noticiasaominuto.com/tech");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        httpCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setUseCaches(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        String codeN = a.toString().split("<div class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 article-thumb-block tech \">")[1];
        codeN = codeN.toString().split("</div>")[0];

        nota = codeN.split("alt=")[1].split("class=")[0].replace("\"", "");

        httpCon.disconnect();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000*30);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("\n \n ERRO TIMER \n \n" + e + "\n \n \n \n");
        }


    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("\n \n ERRO 1 \n \n" + e + "\n \n \n \n");
        return nota+"1";
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("\n \n ERRO 2 \n \n" + e + "\n \n \n \n");
        return nota+"2";
    }

    return nota;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

This is an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: your code works fine for me and returns >> "Magic Leap revelou os seus (prometedores) óculos de realidade aumentada".  Can you provide a full stack trace?

Comment: @PillHead Yes, it is now in post. The code also works for me on java eclipse, but not on android studio

Comment: take a look at this post which has a couple of  suggestions... https://github.com/wit-ai/wit/issues/42